# SPO Rest API recursive call for large document library (5k threshold)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, rest, sharepoint-online

I've got a large document library with 50k files in it. Currently, i'm thrown error message that the query exceeds threshold limit. I added indexes and used all possible filters on my rest api call and still hit the threshold limit on query. I read that a recursive call would allow me to process batches of 5000 and concat into the same output. I wish to display the output using jquery datatables and filter date range parameters are passed from the URL. How to achieve recursive calls?

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    loadItems();
});    
    
  
function loadItems() {    
    var range = GetFromToValues("FromTo");    
    var oDataUrl = "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items?$top=5000&$select=Created,Reg&$filter="+range+"";    
    $.ajax({    
        url: oDataUrl,    
        type: "GET",    
        dataType: "json",    
        headers: {    
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"    
        },    
        success: mySuccHandler,    
        error: myErrHandler    
    });    
}    
  
function mySuccHandler(data) {    
    try {    
          
        $('#table_id').DataTable({    
            "pageLength": 100,
            "dom": 'frtip',
            "aaData": data.d.results,
            "aoColumns": [  
            {"mData": "Created"},             
            {"mData": "Reg"}
            ]    
        });    
    } catch (e) {    
        alert(e.message);    
    }    
}    
    
function myErrHandler(data, errMessage) {    
    alert("Invalid date range");    
}   

        function GetFromToValues(param) {
            var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
                var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
                if (urlparam[0] == param) {
                    return urlparam[1];
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm able to create arrays of 5000 using code below. Can this be merged with my code above to generate the jquery datatable?

````
var response = response || [];
var listURL = "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items?$top=5000&$select=*";
GetListItemsRecursive(listURL);
function GetListItemsRecursive(restURL) {
    $.ajax({
        url: restURL,
        method: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            response = response.concat(data.d.results);
            console.log(data);
            if(data.d.__next) {
                GetListItemsRecursive(data.d.__next);
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
}```
````